# Access to second RTDB in different region

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have issues with access to second RTDB instanace i added to my project.

Default instance is in us-central1

Second instance is in asia-southeast1

My flutter app works fine with USA rtdb. However, App is not able to access second db where rules require auth != null. I removed auth check in rules and it was able to read/write second instance. Access to first default instance works as intended with auth check in rules.

Please help. I want to keep rtdb in multiple regions.

I have downloaded google-serices.json and recomipled app to test but that didn't help.

Comment: Are both databases part of the same Firebase project? If so, the auth state should be passed to the security for both of them in exactly the same way - and the problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, same project. Its so weird. I expected using multiple db to work out of box. What do you suggest to try next @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: DB rules are exactly same for both DBs. I also copied data from the default db to second db to test if empty db could be an issue.

Comment: I have two firebase apps in my flutter app. Each defining one db. I feel i need to auth both firebase apps. Digging more in this direction.